# Using @RunAs with different file-based realm in Payara

Tags: realm, glassfish, payara, java-ee-8

I'm using Payara 5.194 and created a web app (war). This webapp contains a singleton which has a @Schedule which runs some method periodically. It uses @RunAs() to specify a role to use.

```
@Singleton
@RunAs("system")
public class MySingleton {
  @EJB
  MyEjb myEjb;

  @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*", persistent = false)
  public void go()
  {
    myEjb.doSomething(strings);
  }
}
```

I'm using the default file based realm that is provided by payara. I added a user there with the system role and it which works fine.

Now I needed to created a project specific  file based realm for my project:

```
asadmin \
    create-auth-realm \
    --classname com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm \
    --property "file=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/config/project_keyfile:jaas-context=fileRealm" \
    ProjectRealm
```

I added a user

```
asadmin \
    --passwordfile passwordfile.txt \
    create-file-user \
    --authrealmname ProjectRealm \
    --groups group1:system \
    test
```

When I remove the user from the default realm things stop working which is logical.

I want the system to start using the new realm. I tried setting it in the web.xml without luck:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ProjectRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

I know it's possible to tell payara that my new realm is the default but I don't want to do that. Btw this can be done like this

```
set configs.config.server-config.security-service.default-realm=ProjectRealm
```

After further investigation I found that if I wrap this war into an ear and provide the following in the glassfish-application.xml then it works ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-application PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Java EE Application 6.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-application_6_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-application>
  <realm>ProjectRealm</realm>
</glassfish-application>
```

So using an ear its clearly possible to specify the default realm to use. And the @RunAs will honour that. But this is application/ear wide and is not what I want.

But my question is: if I don't use an ear, is there a way to specify the realm to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you hit a bug in Payara Server which is fixed here: https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/4597. The fix will be released in the next version soon.

If you want to test the fix, you can build Payara Server from the master branch. Or just build the `dol` module and replace the `dol.jar` in `modules` directory with the newly built module.